# "android:supportsRtl" isn't work

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, right-to-left

I'm trying to make an app which support RTL and LTR

and i'm using "android:supportsRtl" in the manifest and change layout properties to new start/end equivalents.

similar [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) link

My android is 4.2
but always my layout is LTR! even when i'm using RTL languages on my device
How should I fix my layout to RTL? Because I want to have RTL layout for RTL languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your version of Android Studio and update it!